# Two methods with the same signature, why it works

Tags: java, generics, methods, jvm

I have a class which treats Strings as a collection. These are two methods from the class:

```
@Override
public <B> IndexedSeq<B> map(final Function1<? super Character, B> function) {...}

public RichString map(final Function1<? super Character, Character> function) {...}
```

Just the signature from the methods are relevant to my question.
Now, Eclipse does issue a warning that the two methods have the same erasure. But it still allows me to create them, and they work as expected: Whenever I supply a function which transforms Character to Character, a RichString is returned, as I wanted.

My question is why does it work, since in runtime there's no information about the generic types, and the return of the method is not part of the method signature? How can the JVM knows which of the two methods to call, when I call them?

Edit:

I think, after the erasure, the two methods would have the following signature:

```
@Override
public IndexedSeq map(final Function1<Object, Object> function) {...}

public RichString map(final Function1<Object, Object> function) {...}
```

Which would make them differ only by the return type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct that this shouldn't compile. There's a bug in Java 6 that caused code like this to be incorrectly accepted: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6182950

Comment: I'm no marking yours as a correct answer, because, as I believed, those two methods fallback to the same erasure. And it makes sense that, in JDK 7, this kind of code does not compile anymore.

Comment: I'm actually kind of glad that this is the case (despite the impact on my rep ;-) ). I didn't like not knowing why `String foo(Map<Character, Character> m)` would erase to `String foo(Map m)` (as we all know it does), but `String <B> foo(Map<Character, B> m)` didn't erase to `String foo(Map m)`. I figured it was something weird about using a type parameter as a type argument in a method argument declaration. Am relieved to find it isn't. :-)

Answer (score 1):

1. the runtime has plenty of information about generic types when it comes to class/method signatures, just not when it comes to object instances. The entire signature of the second overload can probably be retrieved by reflection.
2. It doesn't matter, because method overloads are resolved at compile-time anyway. It's possible the ambiguity is resolved there, e.g. by the compiler considering the second overload "more specific" for a parameter of type `Function<Character, Character>`.

Comment: Yes, I do believe that the compiler would know which one to call. But when it would make the bytecode, wouldn't the two methods have the same erasure, causing an error?

Comment: @ViniciusSeufitele I *think* the first one should erase to `IndexedSeq<Object> map(Function1<Object, Object>)` and the second one to `RichString map(Function1<Object, Character>)`. That said, the Java compiler complains about the erasure to me, so I'm not sure what you mean by the code working.

Comment: @ViniciusSeufitele Hm. It compiles under JDK6, but not under JDK7. It seems *something* in the language changed to explain this.

Comment: @ViniciusSeufitele If it's a warning there's a good chance it will become an error when you upgrade to JDK7. Clearly either *something* about the erasure rules changed, or the compiler is being more strict where it accepted wrong code before. I'm not sure you'll get a conclusive explanation from someone outside the actual Java compiler team, seeing how this is a fine nuance of an already arcane mechanism.

Comment: @ViniciusSeufitele For what it's worth, poking at the classes with `javap` shows that all information from the signatures is present in the bytecode. (Erasure doesn't really mean what people think it means - it's not stripping everything between angle brackets.)